# Japanese Characters Escape and Decoding in JS

Tags: javascript

I was trying to write a JavaScript method that **[escapes](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp)** Japanese Characters.

```
var esc_str=escape("チャイナモバイル•リミテッド");
var dec_str=decodeURIComponent(esc_str);
//%u30C1%u30E3%u30A4%u30CA%u30E2%u30D0%u30A4%u30EB%u2022%u30EA%u30DF%u30C6%u30C3%u30C9 is dec_str as per debugger- console log.
console.log(dec_str);
```

While **[decoding](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp)**, I am getting following error:

> Uncaught URIError: URI malformed

How do we escape Japanese Characters, to decode it back properly?

Any help is appreciated!

http://jsfiddle.net/hcU9C/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The page you linked to says

> Note: The escape() function should not be used to encode URIs. Use the encodeURI() function instead.

And that seems to work:

```
encodeURIComponent("チャイナモバイル•リミテッド");
"%E3%83%81%E3%83%A3%E3%82%A4%E3%83%8A%E3%83%A2%E3%83%90%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E2%80%A2%E3%83%AA%E3%83%9F%E3%83%86%E3%83%83%E3%83%89"

decodeURIComponent("%E3%83%81%E3%83%A3%E3%82%A4%E3%83%8A%E3%83%A2%E3%83%90%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E2%80%A2%E3%83%AA%E3%83%9F%E3%83%86%E3%83%83%E3%83%89")
"チャイナモバイル•リミテッド"
```

Comment: encodeURIComponent would also work here. Which one to use depends on if any &, = and the like should also be encoded or not.

Comment: I ask that because you encode with encodeURI and decode with decodeURIComponent. It is weird how you use 2 functions that are not direct opposite of each other.

Answer (score 2):

You should ideally use `encodeURI` or `encodeURIComponent` to encode strings and `decodeURI` or `decodeURIComponent` respectively to decode the string as `escape` & `unescape` have been deprecated.

Still if you wish to use `escape` for encoding then use `unescape` function instead of `decodeURIComponent` function to decode string.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions?#escape_and_unescape_functions%28Obsoleted_above_JavaScript_1.5%29) page,

> The escape and unescape functions do not work properly for non-ASCII
>   characters and have been deprecated. In JavaScript 1.5 and later, use
>   encodeURI, decodeURI, encodeURIComponent, and decodeURIComponent.
>
> The escape and unescape functions let you encode and decode strings.
>   The escape function returns the hexadecimal encoding of an argument in
>   the ISO Latin character set. The unescape function returns the ASCII
>   string for the specified hexadecimal encoding value.