# Need to convert less than greater than marks to entity in Japanese lines

Tags: javascript, php, html, cjk

I have form that submit Japanese content like follows.

"`<div><b>`これを目的に行く価値あり！`</b>`千葉県のご当地グルメ７選 ＜写真0＞　→`<p>`使えそうなものがあれば使う`<p></div>`"

With JavaScript I'm removing these `<b>` and `<p>` html tags.

```
function extractContent(s) {

      var span = document.createElement('span');

      span.innerHTML = s;

      return span.textContent || span.innerText;
};
```

But how do I put these characters "＜写真0＞" as it is?

Page loading error is "**Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token**"

Even I try with with "encodeURIComponent" and "decodeURIComponent" it not worked.

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. Can you show us the code you use to remove HTML tags?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Japanese Characters Escape and Decoding in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656089/japanese-characters-escape-and-decoding-in-js)

Comment: Hi James. about function is my HTML tags remove function.
@AndroidNoobie I have tried it. No luck.

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mcve]. So far you have only shown a function, not even how or where it is called. And what you have shown alone certainly doesn’t throw any error on its own.

Comment: @CBroe I'm sorry if you not get what I asked. I'm new to this. Thanks for reference. When I get this data from database and show in a page the error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works as expected, so probably there is something wrong with the string intself (incomlete unicode symbol?)

```js
var str = '<div><b>これを目的に行く価値あり！</b>千葉県のご当地グルメ７選 ＜写真0＞　→\
  <p>使えそうなものがあれば使う</p>\
</div>';

function extractContent(s) {
      var span = document.createElement('span');
      span.innerHTML = s;
      return span.textContent || span.innerText;
};

console.log(extractContent(str));
```

Comment: Yes Kosh its working like this. But when it coming from database to page it will give the error.

Comment: @damnguy, could you please elaborate on how it comes to page from the server? As a HTML string, JSON, something else?

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be cleaner to iterate through the children (here, the `<b>` and the `<p>`) and grab their `textContent`, rather than try to parse the text as HTML:

```js
let outputStr = '';
[...document.querySelector('div').childNodes]
  .forEach(node => outputStr += node.textContent);
  
console.log(outputStr);
```

```html
<div><b>これを目的に行く価値あり！</b>千葉県のご当地グルメ７選 ＜写真0＞　→
  <p>使えそうなものがあれば使う
  </p>
</div>
```

Or, more functionally, with `reduce`:

```js
const outputStr = [...document.querySelector('div').childNodes]
  .reduce((strSoFar, node) => strSoFar + node.textContent, '');
  
console.log(outputStr);
```

```html
<div><b>これを目的に行く価値あり！</b>千葉県のご当地グルメ７選 ＜写真0＞　→
  <p>使えそうなものがあれば使う
  </p>
</div>
```